# Duda con useEffect en React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo a usar React.js y estoy haciendo una práctica que consiste en atacar a la API de randomuser.me y hacer un componente con datos de 1 usuario
En el App.js tengo:

```
import "./App.css";
import Cabecera from "./components/cabecera";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { ListaPersonas } from "./components/ListaPersonas";

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Cabecera/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<ListaPersonas />}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Tengo este archivo llamado data.js para recoger todos los datos de 10 usuarios (me funciona bien al probarlo con un console.log)

```
const API_URL = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10";

export async function getAllData() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data)
        return data;
    }catch (error) {
        console.log("Error al cargar el fichero");
    }
}
```

Y luego este archivo para 'montar' el listado llamado ListaPersonas.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import * as API from "../services/data";
import Card from "./card";

export function ListaPersonas() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    API.getAllData()
    .then(setData)
    .catch(console.log("error al cargar los datos en ListaPersonas")); //Me salta este error
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {data.length === 0 ? (
        <div>Cargando...</div>
      ) : (
        <section>
          {[data].map((data) => (
            <Card key={data} {...data} /> 
          ))}
        </section>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Y luego aparte tengo el componente Card para mostrar los datos.

El caso es que me da fallo dentro de ListaPersonas.js en el catch:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    API.getAllData()
    .then(setData)
    .catch(console.log("error al cargar los datos en ListaPersonas"));
  }, []);
```

Pero en el archivo de data.js si me recoge bien los datos de la API y no encuentro el fallo.
El caso es que necesito los datos que recojo en el archivo data.js en el archivo ListaPersonas.js

He realizado prácticas similares y no he tenido problemas al realizarlo de esta manera.

Comment: `.then(resp => setData = resp)` prueba con esto. Aunque primero verifica como te esta llegando los datos. Ej: `.then(resp => console.log(resp))`

Comment: @DavElsanto acabo de probar si me llegan los datos y efectivamente llegan pero me sigue saltando el catch al probar esto `then(resp => console.log(resp))`, ahora he probado esto `.then(resp => setData = resp)` y setData lo tengo como const e igualarlo a resp me dice: **Assignments to the 'setData' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps**

Comment: vos dentro del then tenes que definir una funcion, y vos lo que estas haciendo en lugar de eso, es llamar a la funcion ``setData`` que espera un parametro, asi que te va a tirar error. Creeria que lo correcto seria que la funcion en el then quede asi: ``.then(data => setData(data))``

Comment: @AgustinG. he probado también esa forma y tampoco funciona, me salta el catch :( pero al hacer la prueba poniendo un console.log si me muestra los datos

Comment: para, no entiendo que pasa cuando haces ``then(resp => console.log(resp)``. Te muestra el console o entra al catch?

Comment: @AgustinG. al hacer eso me muestra el mensaje de error del catch y seguidamente los datos en consola, muy raro la vardad

Comment: y cual de los dos catch es el que ves?

Comment: @AgustinG. el catch que está dentro del useEffect del archivo ListaPersonas.js    `.catch(console.log("error al cargar los datos en ListaPersonas"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes es en la definición del `catch`:

Lo tienes así:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    API.getAllData()
    .then(setData)
    .catch(console.log("error al cargar los datos en ListaPersonas")); //Me salta este error
  }, []);
```

Y debería ser así:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    API.getAllData()
    .then(setData)
    .catch(e => console.log("error al cargar los datos en ListaPersonas")); 
  }, []);
```

Por esa mala definición es que siempre se ejecuta ese `console.log`

Comment: Graciaaas! No me había dado cuenta, ahora el catch si funciona como debe.